# How to store Date in Database using PHP

Tags: php, html

I tried to store date in database using the following query

```
$ddline = $_POST['deadline'];
INSERT into admin(RegDeadline VALUES('$ddline'))
```

$ddline value is taken from date picker. 
But it is not storing in the databse

Comment: eh? Is that your complete code?

Comment: Show your actual code and SQL. That example would not parse in PHP, nor would the SQL be valid.

Comment: What is this in your SQL query? 'RegDeadline'

Comment: MySQL `date` and `datetime` fields require the date string to be in a very specific format. You haven't told us what `$_POST['deadline']` is in, but if it isn't in that specific format, it won't save correctly to a MySQL `date` field.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your datatype of date in table as `date`.

The standard format of `date` in mysql is `YYYY-MM-DD`, so you should store in same format. You are tryig to insert in different format, so date is getting stored as `0000-00-00`.You can change it to required format using `strtotime()`;

While storing

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['deadline']));
```

While displaying

```
echo date("required format",strtotime($date));
```

For formats, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You should reformat your query as below.

```
INSERT into admin(RegDeadline) VALUES('$ddline');
```

In addition, format your `$ddline` to `YYYY-MM-DD`.